# Postman - How to store multiple values from a response header in a var or just be able to see them

Tags: postman, response-headers

Using a GET in postman with the URL posted below, I am able to store the entire response header in question with all of its data in a var, the issue for me is how do I verify the pieces of data inside that var

**here is my URL**
http://localhost/v1/accounts?pageNumber=1&pageSize=2

[[image: here is my response header[1]]

using postman I am able to get the above in a var

```
var XPaginationData = postman.getResponseHeader(pm.globals.get("PaginationHeader"));
pm.globals.set("XPaginationData", XPaginationData);
```

is there a way to get the individual values inside the response header **X-Pagination** stored in a different var to assert later

using this in postman

```
pm.globals.set("XPaginationData", JSON.stringify(pm.response.headers));
console.log(JSON.parse(pm.globals.get('XPaginationData')));
console.log(JSON.parse(pm.globals.get('XPaginationData'))[4].value);
```

I get [image]

how would i go about getting "TotalCount" for example

**BIG EDIT:**

thanks to a coworker, the solution is this

```
//Filtering Response Headers to get PaginationHeader
var filteredHeaders = pm.response.headers.all()
    .filter(headerObj => {
        return headerObj.key == pm.globals.get("PaginationHeader");

    });

// JSON parse the string of the requested response header
// from var filteredHeaders
var paginationObj = filteredHeaders[0].value;
paginationObj = JSON.parse(paginationObj);


//Stores global variable for nextpageURL
var nextPageURL = paginationObj.NextPageLink;
postman.setGlobalVariable("nextPageURL", nextPageURL);
```

Comment: Is that your response header or the response data? That doesn't look like a header.

Comment: when i send the URL i get
X-Pagination →{"TotalCount":6,"PageSize":2,"CurrentPage":1,"TotalPages":3,"PreviousPageLink":null,"NextPageLink":"http://localhost/v1/accounts?pageNumber=2&pageSize=2"}

Comment: is that not a header?

Comment: Can you update the question with an image of what you're seeing in Postman and I will be able to change my answer to suit this.

Comment: ok check it out, didnt realize i was able to upload images i remember always getting errors attempting to

Comment: Updated my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `JSON.stringfy()` when saving the environment variable and then use `JSON.parse()` to access the different properties or property that you need.

If you set a global variable for the response headers like this:

```
pm.globals.set('PaginationHeader', JSON.stringify(pm.response.headers))
```

Then you can get any of the data from the variable like this:

```
console.log(JSON.parse(pm.globals.get('PaginationHeader'))[1].value)
```

The image shows how this works in Postman. The ordering of the headers returned in the console is inconsistent so you will need to find the correct one to extract data from the `X-Pagination` header

[image: Postman]

Comment: ok i think I am almost there however, console.log(JSON.parse(pm.globals.get('XPaginationData'))[4].value); is giving me {"TotalCount":6,"PageSize":2,"CurrentPage":1,"TotalPages":3,"PreviousPageLink":null,"NextPageLink":"http://localhost:5000/v1/accounts?pageNumber=2&pageSize=2"} not just one object for example: eg: TotalCount

Comment: added new screenshot

Comment: You may also need to `JSON.parse` that value to get what you need, it’s just getting very long winded now. :(

Comment: yeah you aint wrong thanks dude, great answer and i accept it!

Comment: No worries, i’m sure you could refactor that down again.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like an issue with Postman itself.

The only solution that worked for me was to stringify & parse the JSON again, like this:

```
var response = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res))
```

After doing this, the headers and all other properties are accessible as expected.